# is it possible for kiwi tcms to login through Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kiwi-tcms

Is it possible for kiwi tcms to login through Active Directory?

I would like to implement in the company where I work.

I looked for documentation on the internet but without success, is there this possibility or something thought about in this area?